# ScrollTop doesn't work in Safari mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm trying to figure out why a div.scroll-top won't display in Safari mobile.
Tested. It works properly on my iphone in Chrome browser. But Safari seems to be having an issue with calculating a window's height. The div doesn't appear when the browser's scrollbar height reaches a certain number.

HTML
The div container is stored in a bottom of a page inside footer.

```
<div class="scroll-top">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scroll-top {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 3%;
   right: 5%; 
   background: #00316b;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 2px solid #fff;
   display: none;
}

.scroll-top > a {
   display: block;
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 50px;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

Js

```
var scrollTop = $(".scroll-top");
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var topPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (topPos > 300) {
        $(scrollTop).fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        $(scrollTop).fadeOut(200);
    }  

}); 

$(scrollTop).click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Attempted fixing it with vanilla JavaScript, but still no luck.

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    var windowScrollY = window.scrollY;
    if (windowScrollY > 300) {
        document.querySelector(".scroll-top").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.querySelector(".scroll-top").style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Could you give me an idea how to make Safari display div.scroll-top when the browser's scrollbar height is greater than 300?

Comment: `.scroll-top` may not exist when the code is run. have you tried wrapping it in a `window.onload = function(){}` or `$(function(){});`

Comment: Yes. Tried that. Normally, keep the file with js code before the body closing tag and it works well on desktop, tablets, and mobile chrome browsers. Yet it didn't on Safari and Android mobile browsers.
But it started working on mobile devices after I moved the js file to <head>.